# How can Google Hangout App show user a form

Tags: google-hangouts, google-gadget, hangouts-api

We've got our Google Hangout app so that it can display a little message at the end of a broadcast.  We'd like to pop up a form for a user to fill in information about their experience, but we don't want to dominate the entire screen until the end of the broadcast.

Is anyone familiar with having hangout apps change from one display to another during operation?  Our current app has a sidebar style of display.

What we'd really like to have is an interactive popup, perhaps like the "rate this call quality" interactive popup you sometimes see in google hangouts.

We've been reviewing the https://developers.google.com/+/hangouts documentation and the https://developers.google.com/gadgets/ documentation as well as all the example:

https://developers.google.com/+/hangouts/sample-apps

The hangout api developers mailing list seems to have become a general google api G+ community:

https://plus.google.com/u/1/communities/113527920160449995981/s/email

Any help much appreciated